# A Diagonalization argument for Double limsup and /or liminf,

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limsup-and-liminf, double-sequence

Let $\{F(k,n)\,:\:, n\geq 1, m\geq1\}$ be a double sequence family  of extended real numbers $\Bbb R\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$. I would like to prove the following statements

1- There is  $(n_k)_k$, $n_k\to\infty$ as $k\to\infty$ such that

$$\limsup_{k\to \infty} F(k, n_k) \leq  \limsup_{n\to \infty}\limsup_{k\to \infty} F(k,n). $$

2-There is $(n_k)_k$, $n_k\to\infty$ as $k\to\infty$ such that

$$
 \liminf_{k\to \infty} F(k, n_k) \leq  \limsup_{n\to \infty}\liminf_{k\to \infty} F(k,n). 
$$

I am also looking for a good reference for these statements.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3124341/a-diagonalization-argument-involving-double-limits

Answer (score 2):

I'm just going to prove the first statement, the same arguments can be used for the second one **(see edit for a proof of the second statement)**. Let's first assume that the right-hand side of the inequality is $<+\infty$, otherwise we directly have the inequality. For now, let's also assume it's $>-\infty$.

**If** $\,\boldsymbol{-\infty<\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\limsup\limits_{k\to\infty}F(k,n)<+\infty}$:

Since it is $<+\infty$, we have $\limsup_{k\to\infty}F(k,n)<+\infty$ for large enough $n$. Furthermore, since we assumed it's also $>-\infty$, that means there's an infinite and increasing sequence $(n(i))_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that:
$$
-\infty<\limsup_{k\to\infty}F(k,n(i))<+\infty
\ \ \ \ \ \text{ for all } i\geq1.
$$
In particular, $n(i)\underset{i\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} \infty$.

Now that we've ensured this $\limsup$ is finite, let's define a sequence $(k_i)_i$ recursively. Let's just choose $k_0=1$, and for every $i\geq1$, we define $k_i\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k_i > k_{i-1}$ and:
$$
F(k,n(i)) < \limsup_{k'\to\infty} F(k',n(i)) + \frac{1}{n(i)}
\ \ \ \ \ \text{ for all } k\geq k_i.
$$
We can now define our $(n_k)_k$ as follows:
$$
n_k :=
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if } 1\leq k < k_1,\\
n(1) &\text{if } k_1\leq k < k_2,\\
n(2) &\text{if } k_2\leq k < k_3,\\
n(3) &\text{if } k_3\leq k < k_4,\\
\vdots &\vdots
\end{cases}
$$
We can see that $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}n_k = \infty$ and, for all $k\geq k_1$:
$$
F(k,n_k) - \limsup_{k'\to\infty} F(k',n_k) < \frac{1}{n_k},
$$
and so we can write :
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{k\to\infty} F(k,n_k)
&= \limsup_{k\to\infty} \left(F(k,n_k) - \limsup_{k'\to\infty} F(k',n_k) + \limsup_{k'\to\infty} F(k',n_k)\right)
\\
&\leq \limsup_{k\to\infty} \underbrace{\left(F(k,n_k) - \limsup_{k'\to\infty} F(k',n_k) \right)}_{\leq 1/n_k}
+ \limsup_{k\to\infty} \limsup_{k'\to\infty} F(k',n_k)
\\
&\leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} \limsup_{k\to\infty} F(k,n).
\end{align*}
Statement 1 is thus proven when the right-hand side of the inequality is $>-\infty$.

**If** $\,\boldsymbol{\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\limsup\limits_{k\to\infty}F(k,n)=-\infty}$:

When it is $-\infty$, we can instead define $(n(i))_i$ in a similar way to $(k_i)_i$, such that $n(i)>n(i-1)$ and:
$$
\limsup_{k\to\infty} F(k,n(i)) < -i,
$$
and similarly, define $(k_i)_i$ such that $k_i>k_{i-1}$ and:
$$
F(k,n(i)) < -i
\ \ \ \ \text{ for all } k\geq k_i,
$$
and use the same definition for $(n_k)_k$. We still have $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} n_k = \infty$, and:
$$
\limsup_{k\to\infty} F(k,n_k) = -\infty,
$$
and so the inequality is still true.

$ $

**EDIT:**
For the second statement, we can break it down into the same two cases, since we directly have the inequality when the right-hand side is $+\infty$.

**If** $\,\boldsymbol{-\infty<\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\liminf\limits_{k\to\infty}F(k,n)<+\infty}$:

We can define $(n(i))_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ almost like before, as a subsequence of the integers such that :
$$
-\infty<\liminf_{k\to\infty}F(k,n(i))<+\infty
\ \ \ \ \ \text{ for all } i\geq1.
$$
Now let's instead define $(k_i)_i$ as $k_0=1$, and for every $i\geq1$, $k_i$ is such that $k_i>k_{i-1}$ and :
$$
|\,F(k_i,n(i)) - \liminf_{k'\to\infty} F(k',n(i))\,| < \frac{1}{n(i)}.
$$
Reusing the same definition of $(n_k)_k$, we get:
$$
|\,F(k_i,n_{k_i}) - \liminf_{k'\to\infty} F(k',n_{k_i})\,| < \frac{1}{n_{k_i}}
\ \ \ \ \ \text{ for all } i\geq1,
$$
and we can write:
\begin{align*}
\liminf_{k\to\infty} F(k,n_k)
&\leq \liminf_{i\to\infty} F(k_i,n_{k_i})
\\
&\leq \liminf_{i\to\infty} \left(\vphantom{\limsup_k}\right.
\underbrace{F(k_i,n_{k_i}) - \liminf_{k'\to\infty} F(k',n_{k_i})}_{\underset{i\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\, 0}
+ \liminf_{k'\to\infty} F(k',n_{k_i})
\left.\vphantom{\limsup_k}\right)
\\
&\leq \liminf_{i\to\infty} \liminf_{k'\to\infty} F(k',n_{k_i})
\leq \limsup_{i\to\infty} \liminf_{k'\to\infty} F(k',n_{k_i})
\\
&\leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} \liminf_{k\to\infty} F(k,n).
\end{align*}

**If** $\,\boldsymbol{\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\liminf\limits_{k\to\infty}F(k,n)=-\infty}$:

Almost like before, define $(n(i))_i$ such that $n(i)>n(i-1)$ and:
$$
\liminf_{k\to\infty} F(k,n(i)) < -i,
$$
and define $(k_i)_i$ such that $k_i>k_{i-1}$ and:
$$
F(k_i,n(i)) < -i.
$$
Reusing the same $(n_k)_k$ again, we have $n_{k_i} = n(i)$ and:
$$
\liminf_{k\to\infty} F(k,n_k)
\leq \liminf_{i\to\infty} F(k_i,n_{k_i})
= -\infty.
$$

Comment: The second one looks completely different. Do you know any good reference for this?

Comment: The second statement? I don't, but that's true I did kind of underestimate the differences between the two. I've edited my answer to add a proof of statement 2.